# How Proof all Subgroup point of prime order elliptic curve have prime order [#G=#E]?

Tags: elliptic-curves

anyone knows any reference that proof it ? Please Help .

Comment: Do you know Lagranges' theorem?

Comment: Actually, there is one point for which this will not hold.

Comment: Yes, I know Lagranges theorem  ______  I also know Cauchy's theorem ______ But I need some valid reference to proof it. ____ Anyone knows ? :(

Comment: Given Lagrange's theorem (which will be in any decent textbook on number theory), the proof is straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Lagrange you know that the orders of elements in a finite group are divisors of the group order. Now you have a prime order group of order $p$ and thus the possible orders are $1$ and $p$. Now, the identity has order $1$ and are there any other elements different from the identtiy that can have order $1$? (no) What is the remaining choice for the order of the remaining elements?

Comment: Since you seem to have understood the question, could you translate it into English? I can't work out how to parse “Subgroup point of prime order elliptic curve”.

Comment: @Gilles I simply replaced "all subgroup point" with "all points". Its still not really perfect, but makes more sense.

Comment: thanks in advance @DrLecter. The question is : How proof all points on prime order Elliptic Curve $ E : y^2 = x^3 + ax + b (mod p)$ have prime order?
$ \{ \sharp G_{1}, \sharp G_{2}, \sharp G_{3}, ... , \sharp G_{ \sharp E } \} = \sharp E $ where $\sharp G $ is point order and $ \sharp E $ is Elliptic Curve order.

Comment: @DrLecter I am Strongly agree with Lagrange method. BUT is there any valid reference that I cite it in my research ?  ___ Regards

Comment: @saeid you will find it in any textbook that contains some basic group theory.